# strncpy and _tcsncpy c++ example

Tags: c++, string, copy, strncpy

I couldn't find any clear source in google, so I decided ask here.

Functions strncpy and _tcsncpy in c++ accept 3 arguments: destination, source and nCount.

It is not clear for me what is 3rd parameter nCount. Is it amount of characters to be copied or size of buffer in bytes?

Comment: `count - maximum number of characters to copy`. [copy/pasted from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy). I literally just googled "strncpy".

Comment: Googling "strncpy reference" gave nothing? Really? How about [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy)?

Comment: This is easily answerable by google.

Answer (score 0):

> Copies the first num characters of source to destination.

Source : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

You can copy the first `num` bytes using `strlcpy`.